# Парсинг пиров Asterisk по статусу и перезапуск sip шлюза

Tags: bash, asterisk, voip, crontab, expect

Дано:

- Asterisk 192.168.1.50
- Сервер Ubuntu
- VoIP шлюз DVG-2102S 192.168.1.10

Шлюз периодически отваливается от астериска с номером 294. 
На сервере Ubuntu написал скрипт на языке expect который подключается к проблемному шлюзу по telnet и перезагружает его. 
 Запихнул это дело в cron (запуск каждый день в 8:00). Но после перезагрузки номер не всегда регистрируется.
Помогите написать скрипт для парсинга статуса пира и если он не OK, то запуск моего expect скрипта.
Естественно ssh ключи настроены и вручную с сервера Ubuntu можно увидеть статус sip пира.

Comment: Можете модель шлюза указать? Если есть проблемы с регистрацией, можно попробовать перейти на статику на шлюзе и авторизацию на  Asterisk по IP шлюза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Разобрался сам

dlink_check.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
ssh root@192.168.1.50 "asterisk -vx 'sip show peer 294' | grep 
Status" > /home/user/1.txt
if grep "UNKNOWN" /home/user/1.txt;
then /usr/bin/expect /home/user/voip_shop1_reboot.exp
fi
```

voip_shop1_reboot.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet 192.168.1.10
sleep 1
expect "User:"
send "admin\r"
expect "Password:"
send "pass\r"
sleep 1
send "RESTART\r"
send "y"
expect eof
```

crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/dlink_check.sh
```